# Caffe for Windows on VS 2013 failing with leveldbutil error

Tags: visual-studio, caffe

I am trying to compile and run cafee with the directions found here:
https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/caffe-vs2013-opencv-in-windows-tutorial-i/

But when I run it, for example on the MNIST example:

```
"bin\caffe.exe" train --solver=examples\mnist\lenet_solver.prototxt
```

I get the output:

```
Usage: leveldbutil command...
   dump files...         -- dump contents of specified files
```

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling from https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows solved the problem.

Check the users group in case you need help:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/caffe-users

Check the issue tracker in case you need help:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues